# Extend a vector by randomly increasing values in R

Tags: r, random

In this example I'm trying to generate a random time series for 3 individuals at 4 time points (below `x` contains the 1st timepoints for each individual). I want the values to be randomly increasing rather than decreasing in time. Below is my current solution.

```
set.seed(0)
x <- rnorm(3)
x
[1]  1.2629543 -0.3262334  1.3297993
y <- c(x, 
       x*runif(1,.8,1.2), 
       x*runif(1,.9,1.3), 
       x*runif(1,1,1.4))
y
[1]  1.2629543 -0.3262334  1.3297993  1.4642135 -0.3782206  1.5417106  1.6138915 -0.4168839  1.6993107  1.5967772
[11] -0.4124631  1.6812906
```

This has some problems.

1. For each individual the same coefficient is used for calculating the values for same timepoint resulting in identical trends. How could I get a random coefficient for each multiplication? I could use `lapply` but then the vector will be "grouped" by individuals not by timepoints.
2. I don't wish to write the formulas for last timepoints separately and be so precise. Exact coefficients are not important, I just need the values to have a tendency to slightly increase but occasional decreasing should also be allowed. How could I extend the vector more "effectively"?
3. How to make negative values to also increase?

---

I managed to solve this thanks to [Federico Manigrasso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7600734/). The solution is below.

```
TimeSer <- function(num.id, years, init.val) {
  df <- data.frame(id = factor(rep(1:num.id, length(years))), 
                   year = rep(years, each = num.id))
  yrs <- length(years) - 1
  minim <- seq(-.1, by = -.1, len = yrs)
  maxim <- seq(.4, by = .4, len = yrs)
  val <- list(init.val)
  for (i in 1:yrs) {
    val[[i + 1]] <- unlist(lapply(init.val, function (x) {
      x + (x * runif(1, minim[i], maxim[i])) 
      }))
    }
  df$val <- unlist(val)
  df
}

df <- TimeSer(num.id = 3, years = 2006:2016, init.val = rnorm(3,1e5, 1e5))
```

Visual representation of the results:

```
num.id <- length(unique(df$id))
par(mfrow=c(1,num.id))
lapply(1:num.id, function(x) {
  plot(unique(df$year), df$val[df$id == x], type = 'l', col = x)
  })
```

[image: Random time series]

Comment: `x*runif(3,.8,1.2)`

Comment: @Roland Thanks for the tip! I just learned something new about how R handles vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to put the output in a list, It a lot less messy and you can transform into a vector later (using unlist).
This is how I would rewrite your code

```
x<-rnorm(3)
time<-3
output<-list(x) #init output list with initial data

par1<-c(0.8,0.9,1)
par2<-c(1.2,1.3,1.4)
for( i in 1:time){
  a<-unlist(lapply(x,function(x){x+runif(1,par1[i],par2[i])}))

  output[[i+1]]<-a
  x<-a
}
```

let me know if this solves all your problems..

Comment: Thanks! This did solve all the 3 problems. I customized your solution to my needs and included it in the question.